# Java fraction addition

Tags: java

I've done hours of searching on this problem and can't come up with a solution:

```java
public FractionInterface add(FractionInterface operand) {

    int numerator = num*operand.den + operand.num*den;
    int denominator = den*operand.den;

    return new Fraction(numerator, denominator);

}
```

Every example I've found so far has it done this way, but when I try to do it this way, it doesn't compile and gives this error three times for each operand.*:

```
error: cannot find symbol
            int numerator = num*operand.den + operand.num*den;
                                       ^
symbol:   variable den
location: variable operand of type FractionInterface
```

num and den are the private ints. What am I doing wrong? Should I post the entire program? This is a homework problem, so it must be done using this type of method.

Comment: operand.den seems to not to be int type, so you can't add them.
You should post your FractionInterface class/interface

Comment: You cannot refer to private members of the class like that.

Comment: Where you declare your add method ( I quess its something like class Operand)? In java the fields declared private can't be accessed outside the class (in your case its FractionInterface), so you can't 'see' the den variable outside this class.

Comment: It's a private variable and as such you will not be able to access it without accessor methods such as getNum() and getDen(); Also, you can't have private variables inside the interface these must be public/static/final.

Comment: Presumably `Fraction` is a class that implements the `FractionInterface` interface?  So, what methods are there in the `FractionInterface` interface that let us get the numerator and denominator of the fraction?  And why would you split out an interface like this, when it probably makes more sense not to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the private `num` and `den` using the **public accessor methods**.

If the respective accessor methods are `getNum()` and `getDen()`

```
public FractionInterface add(FractionInterface operand) {

    int numerator = num*operand.getDen() + operand.getNum()*den;
    int denominator = den*operand.getDen();

    return new Fraction(numerator, denominator);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Hours wasted on something so simple haha. I already had the Get methods made, I just didn't realize I could use them for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe in order for you to be able to access the den and num members of the operand argument, they must be declared public or protected.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `FractionInterface` is an *interface*. The actual class of `operand` is unknown—in particular, it may not even have member fields `num` and `den`. (You are not allowed to assume it is an instance of `Fraction`.)

Interface `FractionInterface` should define *accessor methods* to retrieve the value of the numerator and denominator. Use those to get the values you need from `operand`.